# Regex to convert string of two-character words to byte[] for use in C#

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to take a string of a form like:

```
"de ad be ef 12 34 56 78"
```

And convert it to a form appropriate to create a C# `byte[]` like:

```
{0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef, 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

This is not quite the complete answer, but it is good enough for me since adding the "{" and "}" characters by hand is not too bad.

I search for

```
[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]
```

and replace with

```
0x$&,
```

The term "$&" in regex means the thing that was just found.

For a vim one-liner use:

```
%s/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/0x$&,/g
```

If anyone has an answer that also does the "{" and "}" automatically as well, please post.